# wx Python fitting screen to controls

Tags: wxpython

This is driving me mad. Got a simple screen, but it will not fit and show all of the controls. What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT]I am running this on Ubuntu 16.4, Python 3.5.3, wx.Python 4.0.0b2 gtk2 (phoenix)[\EDIT]

```
import wx

class MainEdit(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title="Main Edit"):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title=title)
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Fit()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)
        txt_size = (300, 150)
        txt_style = wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.BORDER_SIMPLE|wx.TE_MULTILINE
        self.txt_A = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=txt_size, style=txt_style)
        self.txt_B = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=txt_size, style=txt_style)
        cmd_refresh = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_REFRESH)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(self.txt_A, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(self.txt_B, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(cmd_refresh, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(main_sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainEdit()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[EDIT 2017 11 02 to show image]

This is the effect I get

[image]

[\EDIT]

[EDIT 2017 11 03 11:20]This is the output when I change the code to Rolf's suggestion

```
11:18:29: Debug: ClientToScreen cannot work when toplevel window is not shown
1 (0, 0, 20, 20)
11:18:29: Debug: ClientToScreen cannot work when toplevel window is not shown
2 (0, 0, 320, 389)
3 (0, 0, 400, 250)
```

The screen is still truncated

[/EDIT]

[\EDIT 2017 11 04 09:20]
The following code works:

```
import wx

class MainEdit(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title="Main Edit"):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title=title)
        txt_size = (300, 150)
        txt_style = wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.BORDER_SIMPLE|wx.TE_MULTILINE
        self.txt_A = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=txt_size, style=txt_style)
        self.txt_B = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=txt_size, style=txt_style)
        cmd_refresh = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_REFRESH)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(self.txt_A, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(self.txt_B, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(cmd_refresh, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(main_sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainEdit()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

As you can see I have removed the panel. However, I was told [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHvH9.png) that "The frame should only have one child, a panel."

So what is the recommended way of structuring a wxPython program?[/EDIT]

Comment: This code works for me on wxPython 3.0.2.0 on Windows 7. I usually don't bother with the `Fit()` methods though. You probably don't want to have both `Fit()` and `SetSizerAndFit` however.

Comment: And works for me with  wxPython 4.0.0rc1.dev3430+077db11 on Win10. **Upgrade** to Windows? :)

Comment: I agree. Works on Windows 7, python 3.5.4, wxPython 4.0.0b2. Should I report this behaviour on Linux? And if so, to whom?

Comment: running this on Ubuntu 16.4, Python 3.5.2, wx.Python 4.0.0b2 gtk2 (phoenix) works as expected, IF the `self.Fit()` in `MainEdit` is dropped.

Comment: Or, you can use `panel.Fit()` in `MainEdit` instead of `self.Fit()` I guess it's a clash between fitting it into the panel and then the frame, it's one or the other

Comment: I agree self.Fit() confuses things in Windows, Maybe it does on Ubuntu too, but it does make the frame bigger on the latter

Comment: Sorry, I got that wrong: I think self.Fit(), is essential and so is self.SetSizerAndFit(...). If either are omitted, even on Windows, I don't get the right layout. panel.fit() does nothing

Comment: I'm now confused, is this a question with regarding Ubuntu or windows? I have tested this exclusively on Linux Mint 18.2 which is Ubuntu based (16.04)

Comment: @RolfOfSaxony The problem is solely on Ubuntu. Works pefectly on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code fixes it. I have added a sizer to MainFrame and placed the panel in it. It still does not answer why the original code works on some PCs but not mine

```
import wx

class MainEdit(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title="Main Edit"):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title=title)
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        txt_size = (300, 150)
        txt_style = wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.BORDER_SIMPLE|wx.TE_MULTILINE
        self.txt_A = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=txt_size, style=txt_style)
        self.txt_B = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=txt_size, style=txt_style)
        cmd_refresh = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_REFRESH)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(self.txt_A, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(self.txt_B, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(cmd_refresh, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainEdit()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note that the Fit has to be done at the frame level and not the panel. In fact, if I replace SetSizerAndFit with SetSizer here I get the same problem that I started with.

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark which might disgust you:

Make the frame bigger,

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title=title, size=(250, 520))
```

Leave out, perhaps unnecessarily,

```
#~ self.Fit()
```

Comment: Tried that. No effect. The self.Fit() was born out of desperation. I'll try it on Windows when I can get the D***D  thing running

Comment: Might be worth reporting to the developers as a departure from uniform cross platform behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine on Ubuntu 16.4, Python 3.5.2, wx.Python 4.0.0b2 gtk2 (phoenix

```
import wx

class MainEdit(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title="Main Edit"):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title=title)
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        print (3,self.GetScreenRect())

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        print (1,self.GetScreenRect())
        txt_size = (300, 150)
        txt_style = wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.BORDER_SIMPLE|wx.TE_MULTILINE
        self.txt_A = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=txt_size, style=txt_style)
        self.txt_B = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=txt_size, style=txt_style)
        cmd_refresh = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_REFRESH)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(self.txt_A, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(self.txt_B, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(cmd_refresh, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(main_sizer)
        print (2,self.GetScreenRect())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainEdit()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The initial screen is displayed as:
[image]

Try the edited code above and watch the screen size adapt to the changes.
See if it gives you any mileage.
Note: I've opted for using `parent` rather than `frame`

Comment: Interesting Ralph. As you will see from my edited question I still do not get your result on ostensibly the same s/w system. Is it possible some dependencies need updating?

Comment: Sorry, "Rolf". Good to know it's not the fundamental code at fault

Comment: @Psionman And is that with the `self.Fit()` in `MainEdit` because that stuffs my system as well. The above code, does NOT have the `self.Fit()`

Comment: My picture in the question is the frame generated by the code in your answer

Comment: @Psionman My final measurement is `3 (0, 0, 400, 494)`, the others are near identical. As a final Hail Mary, try different themes in the Control Center, you never know!

Comment: Changing theme has no effect. I am using Mint. Could that affect the display?

Comment: I have a solution, but this raises a further question. See my edited question